# Pronunciation and characters for 打 110 Without Arabic numerals

Tags: grammar

Memrise provides a phrase that sounds like da yoyo liang. Is yi becoming yo here, and if so under what circumstances would this change occur? Is it just a dialect issue or standard mandarin.
[image: memrise]

Answer (score 3):

In characters, the phrase is

> <sub>**Dǎ yāo yāo líng**</sub>
>
> 打幺幺零
>
> *Dial 1-1-0*

「一」is not **yāo**; rather, a different word「幺」is used. See [Pronunciation of 壹 / 一 in Mandarin](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/29277/pronunciation-of-%e5%a3%b9-%e4%b8%80-in-mandarin?noredirect=1&lq=1) for the use of **yāo**.

Answer (score 1):

"da yoyo liang" seems like a **dialectal** way to say **打110**.

“da yoyo liang” sounds like a Shanghainese version **of 打112**.

Comment: "yoyo" is the OP's attempt at transcribing yāo. I don't think a learning program like Memrise is going to use a dialect recording to teach Mandarin.

Comment: @droooze, we don't really know unless we could hear it. :( It's all guess work here.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it is this

> 打110
>   打一一零
>   dǎ yāo yāo líng

(It's the police emergency phone number.)

It is very common practice in mainland China to say "yāo" in place of "yī" when *pronouncing phone numbers*.  I've heard it's because 一 (yī) and 七 (qī) sound so similar.

I don't believe pronouncing yī as yāo is done outside of phone numbers, e.g., 2011年 would be pronounced “èr líng yī yī nián”.  See https://chinese4kids.net/year-month-date-in-chinese/

It's not used when you're reading numbers normally, 我想买一百一十一个 is "wǒ xiǎng mǎi yībǎi yīshíyī gè".

When I went to Taiwan, the famous building 台北101 was pronounced by the taxi driver “Táiběi yī líng yī”, so my impression this is a mainland China custom.

Comment: Just like reading letters as Alfa, Bravo. Yāo is the stander way to read 1 over radio in military field. For example, when counting down the launch of rocket, the speaker says San, Liang, Yao instead of San, Er, Yi.